# Custom Build (Sublime Text, Latextools)

Tags: xetex, miktex, sublime-text, latextools

I'm trying to customise the build function on Sublime text 3 to include separate outputs for the build files and the pdf. I am using Miktex and xelatex (by adding %!TEX program = xelatex) at the top of my document. How would I customise the Latextools compiler to add,

```
-aux_directory=../intfiles
```

and

```
-output-directory=../pdffiles
```

Which I believe will do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: LaTeXTools now supports `aux_directory` and `output_directory` via settings or using comments such as `%!TEX output_directory = out_dir`. There are a few caveats to this support which are included [in the documentation](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/blob/master/README.markdown#output-directory-and-auxiliary-directory).

---

LaTeXTools doesn't support `-aux-directory` or `-output-directory` (yet). However, if you can stomach having a couple of [symbolic links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365680(v=vs.85).aspx) in the same directory as your main tex document, you can use something like roeeebar's suggestion from [this issue](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/98#issuecomment-182246868), which adds a settings block to your sublime-project file (I've modified this for Windows, but I haven't tested it).

```
"settings": {
    "builder": "script",
    "builder_settings":
        "windows": {
            "script_commands": [
                "latexmk -cd -f -xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -auxdir=Aux -outdir=Output $file_name",
                "mklink Output\\$file_base_name.pdf .",
                "mklink Output\\$file_base_name.synctex.gz .",
                "mklink Aux\\$file_base_name.log ."
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This basically places symbolic links to the appropriate files where LaTeXTools expects to find them, so it should continue to work as expected.

A couple of notes:

1. `latexmk` is not installed by default on MiKTeX. It's easily installable using the package manager, but because it's a Perl script, you'll also need a version of Perl, such as Active Perl or Strawberry installed and on your `%PATH%` to get it working. Unfortunately, the usual builder LaTeXTools uses on MiKTeX (`texify`) will stop with a fatal error if you try to pass it the `-aux-directory` or `-output-directory` flags.
2. You may need to alter the `latexmk` command of you are not using `xelatex`.

Comment: I installed Strawberry Perl, but how would you install it on your '%PATH%' to get it working?

Comment: @JindhaSingh it should do it automatically. Try typing `perl -version` in a cmd.exe window. If you get an error, [see this answer on superuser](http://superuser.com/a/284351).

Comment: @JindhaSingh any progress?

Comment: Yeah i cant get it to work unfortunately. Im still trying, but yeah it wont compile.

Comment: Do you get an error of some sort?